How do you animate hair without losisng its shape?
I want to animate hair I have created using particle system and particles edit. But whenever I enable hair dynamics, it loses the hair styling I did (like bangs with sharp tips). How would I animate hair without losing my hair styling?

“You can’t.” - Jax

hello maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com

maybe set the Thickness Outer of the Collision of the New Head object to the lowest value?

That takes away the weird bouncy effect it was having, but I mean the hair is still getting straightened out. Its losing the combing I did on it whenever it moves. Thats what I am trying to tend to
